# Redirection from statement php page to a modal

Tags: php, jquery, bootstrap-modal

Is it possible to generate a redirection from php validation page to a modal without coding header location to retrieve session values. I tried to reset page and modal but it seems to be impossible modal opened and have to stay opened).

Thanks.

It's a part of my php validation page and Icode three session value to retrieve them in phase 2 form. But I've problem with reload page and modal. So I was thinking for a redirection.

If you need my jQuery ajax code too  please ask.

Thanks a lot and sorry for my English.

```
if ($part->affected_rows > 0)
{
while ($data = $result->fetch_assoc()):
   $clt_id = $data["clt_id"];
   $civil = $data["clt_civil"];
   $name= $data["clt_name"];        
endwhile;
$_SESSION['clt_id'] = $clt_id;
$_SESSION['civil'] = $civil;
$_SESSION['name'] = $name;
```

}

Comment: Have you tried using jquery and ajax?

Comment: Yes I've tried but I don't succeed; I'm  just beginner with ajax. I was just able to retrieve an 'echo json-encode' and I would like to manage the datas in other way.

Comment: it isn't very clear as to what you want. Please add a sample code too..

Comment: i had a peace of validation php page where I initialize the session value.